# Associated graded object

Tags: homological-algebra

I have a question, how do I prove the following proposition? A  and B are filtered chain complex , 
$f: A \rightarrow B $  is a filtered chain map if indicated mapping on the associated graded object of $f: A \rightarrow B $ be quasi-isomorphism then  $f: A \rightarrow B $  is quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? What if you take two chain complexes which are just a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree 0 and trivial elsewhere, filter the first one by $0 \leq 4\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$ and the second one by $0\leq 2\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$, and consider the identity map; the identity respects the filtration, is a quasi-iso (which is equivalent to iso in this case), but the associated gradeds are not isomorphic.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic  thanks,   do you have a proof for other direction?

Comment: You could consider multiplication by 3 from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and filter both of them by $\cdots \leq 16\mathbb{Z} \leq 8\mathbb{Z} \leq 4\mathbb{Z} \leq 2\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$; then the induced map on associated gradeds is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and other direction are true. You can use from Five-lemma and following proposition to proof them.
The chain map $f: C \rightarrow C'$ is quasi-isomorphism if and only if homology of mapping cone of f be trivial.